# how to display UIPickerview in dialog box

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone.

I need to display UIPickerview in UIAlertView and I need to get UIPickerview selected value.

Can anyone please post some code or link?

Comment: When you write "dialog box" do you mean a UIAlertView or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will not do it.

1. I am afraid it is not possible to 'pack' UIPickerView into UIAlertView. UIPickerView seems to be always AS wide AS the whole screen (at least on the iPhone) - so even if you manage to add the picker as a subview, it will cover the alert.
2. I think it will spoil Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Why do you insist to present a picker in alert? Can't you present it alone, without alert?

Comment: This no longer appears to be the case - see the 
accepted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361177/sizing-a-uipickerview-inside-a-uialertview

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not doing that. Use the picker view as it's intended—as it's used in Clock and Calendar, i.e. at the bottom of the screen—and you're much less likely to get your app rejected by Apple for violating their Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

As for the alert, you could create something yourself that looks similar, but I don't see why you'd want to combine a alert and a datePicker.

To access the datePicker's date, you need to have it declared in your code.  Then you can simply use this:

```
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
```

To get the date from a datePicker named `datePicker`.

To get this date into a string, which you probably want, do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```