# Sizing a UIPickerView inside a UIAlertView

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uialertview

I'm trying to put a `UIPickerView` in a `UIAlertView` however I can't seem to size it correctly. Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Select item from list", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 60))
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self

    alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

    alertView.addAction(action)
    parent.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: add more height to picker, 60 is not enough, try 300 or smthing like that

Comment: Have you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/40191156/6433023

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is:

- use multiple lines for message to give space for your new view
- adjust the size of the new view when the alert view is presented

  ```
  let alertView = UIAlertController(
      title: "Select item from list",
      message: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",
      preferredStyle: .alert)

  let pickerView = UIPickerView(frame:
      CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 260, height: 162))
  pickerView.dataSource = self
  pickerView.delegate = self

  // comment this line to use white color
  pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

  alertView.view.addSubview(pickerView)

  let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

  alertView.addAction(action)
  present(alertView, animated: true, completion: { _ in
      pickerView.frame.size.width = alertView.view.frame.size.width
  })
  ```

[image]

Comment: Would this get rejected in the appstore?

Comment: @VlpplpRyguy I had this trick on .actionSheet style and no rejection from App Store.